# How to search value exist in array of objects of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ede1b6c317aca326c2f18d7"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2020-06-11T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "userHolder" : [
        {
            "time" : "12:00",
            "user" : [ 
                "5ede1ff42b3e633edc0ba10e"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "time" : "16:30",
            "user" : []
        }
    ],
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ede1b6c317aca326c2f18d8"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2020-06-121T18:30:00.000Z"),
    "userHolder" : [ 
        {
            "time" : "12:30",
            "user" : [ 
                "5ede1ff42b3e633edc0ba10f"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "time" : "13:00",
            "user" : [ 
                "5ede1ff42b3e633edc0ba10e"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "time" : "12:00",
            "user" : [ 
                "5ede1ff42b3e633edc0ba10f"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "time" : "16:30",
            "user" : []
        }
    ],
}
```

I split the half hour entry. i,e full day 48 columns on userHolder columns. Like 12:30, 13:00, 13:30 and so on. If user not have entry then that column will not create.
So if I want to search **5ede1ff42b3e633edc0ba10e** this id on the complete table then how to write the query.

I tried to use **>$all** operator but this not works on nested structure.

There is a **$elemMatch** but for that query will be too large as I have to write the 48 conditions of timestamp. Expected result is query return the _id of the entry so that it will clear that these id will exist on n numbers of entry. I want the Data not count.

Any help is really appreciated for that.

Comment: Could you please add your expected output, so that your question would be more clear.

Comment: This might help you: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/

Comment: @MilanRegmi I updated the question. I need the data in which my id is exists

Comment: You can simply do this ```db.collection.find({
  "userHolder.user": "5ede1ff42b3e633edc0ba10e"
})``` if you previously know which id you are going to search.